# Conflict in function to allow single post template based on category

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, templates, single

I've used [Justin Tadlock's great function for category specific custom post templates](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/06/creating-single-post-templates-in-wordpress) many times, where you can use **single-cat-id.php** for single posts belonging to a specific category. I just ran into a problem though working on a new site that needs to use the **single-{posttype}** template for a custom post type. The function seems to prevent the custom posts from using **single-{posttype}** template.

**Here's the applicable code:**

```
/* Define a constant path to our single template folder */
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH . '/single');

/* Filter the single_template with our custom function*/
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

/* Single template function which will choose our template*/
function my_single_template($single) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

/* Checks for single template by category. Check by category slug and ID */
foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :

    if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

    elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';

endforeach;

/*Checks for default single post files within the single folder */
if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php';

elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php';

return $single; }
```

Any thoughts on how to modify the following code to allow both the original function of **single-cat-id** as well as **single-{posttype}**?

Comment: Hi Chris, please be sure check out the [editting help page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for help with formatting your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for your post type single-{post-type}.php first try this:

```
/* Define a constant path to our single template folder */
define(SINGLE_PATH, TEMPLATEPATH . '/single');

/* Filter the single_template with our custom function*/
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

/* Single template function which will choose our template*/
function my_single_template($single) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

/* Checks for single template by post type */
if ($post->post_type == "POST TYPE NAME"){
    if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-' . $post->post_type . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
}

/* Checks for single template by category. Check by category slug and ID */
foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :

    if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->slug . '.php';

    elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
        return SINGLE_PATH . '/single-cat-' . $cat->term_id . '.php';

endforeach;

/*Checks for default single post files within the single folder */
if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/single.php';

elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php'))
    return SINGLE_PATH . '/default.php';

return $single; 
}
```

and just replace "POST TYPE NAME" with your custom post type name.

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was something like this but couldn't quite get it worked out. Many thanks!